# indexing _index field in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana-4

I have indices which do not correlate to certain dates/time ranges, they instead correlate to data sources(however are considered the same _type, this structure is a must for my purposes)

I would simply like to be able to filter by index (and therefore make a visualizer which allows users to click and search by index),

I have noticed that the _index field is not indexed!  so I went along and found this

```
 {
     "tweet" : {
         "_index" : { "enabled" : true }
      }
 }
```

in the api docs, however after running this on all(and I can see that the command stuck when fetching my mappings for the indices) however when checking in kibana 4 it still says false in regards to the field being indexed(rendering it unsearchable!)

am I missing a command? or a silly option in kibana 4 that lets you switch indices?(they have similary name structures foo_[locationSource] and my default mapping/index is routed to foo_*

thank you all

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following command (Marvel Sense syntax):

```
PUT /yourIndex/tweet/_mapping
{
     "tweet" : {
         "_index" : { "enabled" : true }
      }
}
```

Comment: right, as said i put in this command, and then this command stuck when i fetch the mapping     "jdbc": {
            "_ttl": {
               "enabled": true,
               "default": 604800000
            },
            "_index": {
               "enabled": true
            },
            "properties": {...

Answer (score 0):

First create any filter by clicking the "filter by value" ("+" magnify glass icon) from results, then edit that filter and update the query with your _index name.

Example:

```
{
 "query": {
  "terms": {
   "_index": [
    "logstash-2016.09.28"
   ]
  }
 }
}
```